# How can I render a sequence created in the video sequence editor?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

I loaded 320 PNG files as an image sequence in the Video Sequence Editor and then applied a speed control effect strip to extend the sequence length to 960 frames (it's stop motion intended to be played at 10fps, but my final movie is going to be 30 fps).

Now I'm scratching my head - How can I now use this slowed down movie as input for another step? Ideally, I can just hook it into the composer (but I couldn't find how). Alternatively, I don't mind rendering the sequence to a movie or image sequence, but I couldn't find how to.

In [Overview of the Sequence Editor](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Sequencer/Usage) it just says "When you click Render or Anim to generate an image or video..." but where do I click?!?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your screen layout to be able to see the properties.
2 choices :
-From the layout menu, choose *Default*
[image]
-From the frame menu, choose properties
[image]

From there, choose the *render* tab and you'll get the render and animation buttons.
You'd better check the hilighted parameters in *dimensions* before rendering. (resolution, frame range, frame rate)
[image]
and also *output* (path/name, file type (images/video/codec...))
[image]

Comment: no render tab... 2.80

Comment: @ses In 2.8x tabs are verticals, you'll find the settings in "output properties" tab. Render and render animation buttons have been removed but you can use F12 and Ctrl+F12 or use the render menu (upper left, close to file and edit menus)